# Jhipster initialization log on Kibana

Tags: logging, kibana, jhipster

I have a jhipster application that sends all the logs to Kibana and works quite well, the problem is that it's only sent to Kibana after the application has already started. If I have an error in the initialization that stops the application, I can't see on Kibana and I need to connect in the server to look the docker logs.

Does someone know how to add the initialization log to Kibana?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Before logback is fully initialized, logstash appender has not been started yet and so logs are written to standard output. So you could redirect java process output to a file and then use FileBeat to push it to your Elastic Search cluster. At least that's how I'd do it in a VM, don't know for Docker.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thank you. I'm gonna try that.